# Randomize parts of a puzzle

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java and right now I'm trying to "solve" this puzzle:
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/puzzle/

Everything is clear to me, but I want to add something. As you can see, when you run it, the puzzle is already solved, so I want to add an algorithm that puts the parts of the image randomly. Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you initialize the images you should put it into a `List` and then use `Collections::shuffle` to shuffle the `List`:

```
List<Image> croppedImages = new ArrayList<Image>(4 * 3);

for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        croppedImages.add(createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                    new CropImageFilter(j*width/3, i*height/4, 
                        (width/3)+1, height/4))));
    }
}

Collections.shuffle(croppedImages);
```

Now in the loop where you initialize the pieces:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if ( j == 2 && i == 3) {
            label = new JLabel("");
            centerPanel.add(label);
        } else {
            button = new JButton();
            button.addActionListener(this);
            centerPanel.add(button);

            button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(croppedImages.get(0)));
            croppedImages.remove(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a note: Naïvely shuffling the list can result in an unsolvable puzzle. Technically you need an even number of inversions, i.e. number pairs in the list that are not in the right order so that the puzzle has a solution. An easier way to get a random starting point would be to simply perform a number of random moves (move squares in valid moves a bunch of times).